# Erro ao usar replicate() e cor() com pontos (`dots`) dentro de uma função

Tags: r

Escrevi uma função para estimar o valor de *p* de correlações por permutação, usando pontos para passar argumentos adicionais para `cor`. Aqui uma versão simples para teste:

```
set.seed(86)

permCorTest <- function(x, y, n = 1e3, ...) {
  obs <- cor(x, y, ...)
  per <- replicate(n, cor(x, sample(y), ...))
  c(cor = obs, p = mean(abs(per) >= abs(obs)))
}

with(mtcars, permCorTest(mpg, qsec, method = "k"))
#> Error in cor(x, sample(y), ...) : invalid 'use' argument
```

O erro é gerado pelo uso dos pontos em `cor` dentro da `replicate`. Posso separar as duas para a função funcionar:

```
permCorTest2 <- function(x, y, n = 1e3, ...) {
  obs <- cor(x, y, ...)
  yr <- replicate(n, sample(y))
  per <- apply(yr, 2, function(s) cor(x, s, ...))
  c(cor = obs, p = mean(abs(per) >= abs(obs)))
}

with(mtcars, permCorTest2(mpg, qsec, method = "k"))
#>       cor         p
#> 0.3153652 0.0180000
```

Ou usar `sapply` ao invés de `replicate`. Mas gostaria de entender o que leva a esse erro nessa situação. Tem alguma forma de passar os argumentos adicionais para `cor` dentro da `replicate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que o erro deve acontecer pela forma como `replicate` avalia a expressão.

```r
replicate
#> function (n, expr, simplify = "array") 
#> sapply(integer(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)), 
#>     simplify = simplify)
#> <bytecode: 0x00000217b6529060>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

Para contornar isso podemos criar uma função temporária que captura os argumentos passados por `...`

```r
set.seed(86)
permCorTest3 <- function(x, y, n = 1e3, ...) {
  obs <- cor(x, y, ...)
  tmp_foo <- function()  cor(x,sample(y), ...)
  per <- replicate(n, tmp_foo()) 
  c(cor = obs, p = mean(abs(per) >= abs(obs)))
}

with(mtcars, permCorTest3(mpg, qsec, method = "k"))
#>       cor         p 
#> 0.3153652 0.0180000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>